# adding react routes to router in react produces blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

whenever add routes to my react component the page becomes blank with no error messages. The only time it occurs is when I add routes to my Nav.js file within the Switch. Here is the code I have:

Nav.js:

```
import React from "react";
import './Nav.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { Routes } from '../routes';
import BrowserRouter
import { Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Design from "../Design";
import Main from '../Main';


// import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
// import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';


const Nav = () => {
    return (
      <Router>
      
      <div className="Nav">
      <div className="head">
       <div id="title">
        WKO
        <div id="bar"></div>
       </div>
       <div className="headlist">
        
         <ul >
         <li><NavLink to="/" style={{color: 'aliceblue', textDecoration: 'none' }} activestyle={{color: 'red'}}>Home</NavLink></li>
         <li><NavLink to="/" style={{color: 'aliceblue', textDecoration: 'none'}} activestyle={{color: 'red'}}>Foundation</NavLink></li>
         <li><NavLink to="/design" style={{color: 'aliceblue', textDecoration: 'none'}} activestyle={{color: 'red'}}>Design</NavLink></li>
         <li><NavLink to="/" style={{color: 'aliceblue', textDecoration: 'none'}} activestyle={{color: 'red'}}>OteyBakes</NavLink></li>
         <li><NavLink to="/" style={{color: 'aliceblue', textDecoration: 'none'}} activestyle={{color: 'red'}}>LLR</NavLink></li>
         <li><NavLink to="/" style={{color: 'aliceblue', textDecoration: 'none'}} activestyle={{color: 'red'}}>Shop</NavLink></li>
         <Switch> 

          <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
          <Route exact path='/design' component={Design} /> 
          </Switch>
         </ul>
         {/* {Routes} */}
         
         
        
       </div>
      </div> 
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }

export default Nav;
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You don't even see the Nav?  What URL are you visiting?

Comment: @BillDoughty I'm using localhost and I see nothing at all but a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See sandbox for working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-noether-27wl4?file=/src/App.js

Notes:

- router should wrap around app in index.js
- switch and routes should be in app.js
- aliceblue is not a registered css color
- ul listStyleType removes bullets, not li textDecoration
- activestyle should be activeStyle
- use render instead of component attribute for better performance
- map your routes rather than hard code for cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to say without working code,
but you can try to change NavLink and Route:

```
<NavLink exact to="/" style={{/*your style'/}} activestyle={{color: 'red'}}>Home</NavLink>
```

and

```
<Route path='/design' exact component={Design}></Route>
```

If it does not work, you can post your code here https://codesandbox.io/, in order to help you.